# TokenMismatchException , despite excluding route

Tags: php, laravel-5, csrf

Im trying to create an img upload using ajax .
Im using the plugin https://github.com/Vinelab/mr-uploader ,and i'm getting CSRFTokenMismatchException . 
Iv'e solved the issue before by adding the route to $execpet on verifyCsrf

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/admin/upload'
    ];

}
```

Since solving the problem the first time i've reveted the whole project back to laravel 5 from laravel 5.1 (long story , i've had to do it ) 
now the problem appears agian .
when trying to send a post request to that route i get 'TokenMismatchException'.

Comment: share your ajax code  ? and also blade.

Comment: the ajax code is a part of the plugin/library that i mentioned .

Comment: the problem is that even if i'm trying to send a bare post reqouest im getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Method 1: Disable CSRF Protection

Add the following code in VerifyCsrfToken.php

This route will ignored from checking csrf token..

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //disable CSRF check on following routes
        $skip = array(
                    '/admin/upload',
                    );

        foreach ($skip as $key => $route) {
            //skip csrf check on route
            if($request->is($route)){
                return parent::addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
            }
        }
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
```

> Method 2: Add CSRF TOKEN in ajax request

```
var token      = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

    $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url  : "/admin/upload",
         data : {_token:token},


 });
```

Comment: add it to the vendor  or to app/http/verifyCSRFToken ?

Comment: don't skip , provide csrf token with ajax request, its not safe to restrict to upload anybody.

Comment: add in `app/Http/Middleware/verifyCSRFToken.php`

Comment: it returns 
`Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::handle() must be an instance of App\Http\Middleware\Closure, instance of Closure given, called in E:\working-Dir\maaleGilboa5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php on line 125 and defined`

Comment: @Rishi how do i add that to the ajax ? i tried something like :type: `"POST",
                url: url,
                cache: !1,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    _token: csrf,
                    photo: photo,
                    meta: meta,
                    crop: crop
                },`